# Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can convert $files contain to array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847541/how-can-convert-files-contain-to-array)

i use of codeigniter. I have this error, How do I solve it?

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: admin/tour.php
Line Number: 81
```

this is line 80:

```
$files = $this->multi_upload->go_upload();
        var_dump($files);
        $images = array();     
        foreach ($files as $img) {   //line 81
          $images[] = $img['file'];
        }
```